# what is the difference between everywhere and anywhere

Tags: meaning, word-choice, any-every

I checked the difference between *anywhere* and *everywhere* in the Longman dictionary. I have understood that when the place is not important we have to use *anywhere* for example:

> You can find a man anywhere but not a businessman everywhere.

But I do not know how to use this general rule in all times. For example, what is the appropriate word for the gap:

> I lost my glasses. I looked `________`, but I couldn't find them.

Is it true that generally the usage of *anywhere* is in negative and question sentences?

Comment: I have looked everywhere, but could not find anything anywhere

Comment: Everywhere is more specific. Each place. Anywhere is vaguer - it can be anywhere

Comment: Have you checked http://english.stackexchange.com/q/120800/14666 *Q: Word-choice question: “His camera accompanied him everywhere/wherever he went in the world.”*?

Comment: @Kris I've taken the liberty of adding that question to the list at the end of my answer. Hope that's OK with you. Thanks.

Comment: **Re: Close-votes** I don't believe this is GR. It is not easy to understand the differences from dictionaries, hence the multiple previous questions about *anyone/everyone* - *they* have not been closed as GR (altho' some have been closed as duplicates), so why should this be?

Comment: The question should have been migrated to ELL. This is a classic ESL topic that non-native learners go through.[Googling for *any* and *every*](https://www.google.com/search?ei=0ylAWoSAGsP0jwOWhIT4BQ&q=any+every+-stackexchange&oq=any+every+-stackexchange&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22341.27152.0.27394.17.16.1.0.0.0.87.974.16.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.167...0j0i22i30k1.0.WfJJl5DN51Y) is better help than adding this Q&A here (IMHO).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You lose a pair of glasses. You start off by saying:

- "*My glasses could be* ***anywhere***." = I don't know where my glasses are. They could be here, there, up, down. In that room, or in another room. I don't know. The glasses are in ***one*** of those many different places.

after a few minutes of searching you might say:

- "*I've looked **everywhere** for my glasses*." = I've looked here, there, up, down, in one room, in another but with no luck. Conclusion: I still don't have my glasses.
- "*I know my glasses must be* ***somewhere***" = They are not here, there, up, nor down, in one room or in another. But they can't have disappeared. I had those glasses just a minute ago. Where are they?

I ask my wife where my glasses are. She always knows where things are.

- "*Do you know where my glasses are? I can't find them* ***anywhere***." = I've looked everywhere but I **didn't find** them in **any** of the places I looked.

My wife replies patiently

- "Yes I do, as a matter of fact, they're on your head."

Answer (score 7):

Think of the difference between ***any*** and ***every***.

> **any *adj*** <sup>[1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=any&title=21st)</sup>
>   1. one, no matter which • *can't find any answer*.
>   2. some, no matter which • *have you any apples?*
>   [other definitions omitted]
>
> **every *adj*** <sup>[2](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=every&title=21st)</sup>
>   1. each one or single of a number or collection; omitting none.
>   [other definitions omitted]
>
> **any <sup>[3](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/any_1)</sup>**
>   2. used to refer to a person or thing of a particular type when what you are saying is  true of all people or things of that type:
>    *- Any child who breaks the rules will be punished.
>
>    - Always check the details carefully before you sign any written agreement.
>
>    - I can see you any time on Monday.
>
>    - If I can help in any way, let me know.*
>   [other definitions omitted]
>
> **every <sup>[4](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/every)</sup>**
>   1. used to refer to all the people or things in a particular group or all the parts of something:
>    - *We looked carefully at every car that drove past.
>
>    - Every child will receive a certificate at the end of the course.
>
>    - I enjoyed every minute of the film.
>
>    - I listened carefully to every word he said.*
>   [other definitions omitted]

In general terms:

- **any** is referring to *one or more* items, people, or places *individually*
- **every** is referring to *all* items, people, or places *collectively*

So you can then apply those prefixes to get the words ***anywhere, everywhere - anyone, everyone***, with the prefixes carrying over their individual meanings. Hence:

- **everywhere** = *all* places
- **anywhere** = *one or more* places

Therefore, when searching for something, you might say:

- **I looked everywhere, ...** = I looked in *all* places
- **... but I couldn't find it anywhere** = I could not find it in *any one* of the places I looked; I found it in *not one (none)* of the places.

If you had said "I couldn't find it ***everywhere***", it would have meant "I could not find it in *all* places (but I *did* find it in *some* places)."

So if you have lost a particular item, you look in *all* places (***everywhere***), with the hope of finding it in *one* of the places (***anywhere***).

In a different situation, such as in a busy city, you might say:

- "There are cars and people *everywhere*: there is *nowhere* that is quiet."
  ***nowhere*** = *not anywhere*

Going back to your original question:

- I would say that you "use *anywhere*" when you are referring to a *single* place, the location of which is immaterial (doesn't matter). [I'm avoiding using "important" because that can have other meanings.]
- You are correct in suggesting that "*anywhere*" is *often* used in a negative clause; e.g. "I couldn't find it *anywhere*"
- and also that "*anywhere*" is *often* used in a question; e.g. "Is there *anywhere* (any one place) that I could get a coffee?"

---

Before answering this question, I looked for any previous questions that had addressed this issue. I couldn't find any, but I did find several previous questions that discussed *anyone* & *everyone*. You may find some of those useful:

- [Open for “anyone”? Or open for “everyone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/open-for-anyone-or-open-for-everyone/2850)
- [Difference between “anyone” and “everyone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103930/difference-between-anyone-and-everyone/103933)
- [What is the difference between “anyone” and “everyone” in this context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77058/what-is-the-difference-between-anyone-and-everyone-in-this-context/77069)

This previous question may also be of interest (although it doesn't discuss the word *anywhere*):

- [His camera accompanied him everywhere/wherever he went in the world.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120800/word-choice-question-his-camera-accompanied-him-everywhere-wherever-he-went-in)

Answer (score 3):

The term *anywhere* is indefinite. No particular place is identified or chosen.

The term *everywhere* is definite. Every single possible place is identified or chosen.

In your final example, the sentence should read

> I lost my glasses. I looked *everywhere* but I couldn't find them.

because you definitely look in each particular place they might be.

There is also a sense that *everywhere* suggests multiple incidents of the object or action identified. *Anywhere* may refer to just one element or multiple elements.

> He sowed the grass seed *everywhere*.
>
> He could have planted that [one] tree *anywhere*.
>
> He could have planted those[many] trees *anywhere*

Sometimes they are equivalent.

> You can buy my book *anywhere*.
>
> You can buy my book *everywhere*.