# What's the difference between "any" and "every"?

Tags: meaning, any-every

When I see "every" and "any", I think they have the same meaning but it's not actually so! 
To be more specific, what's the difference between "everything/anything", "everytime/anytime", "everywhere/anywhere" and things like these...

Comment: Consider this post, which extends to the prefixes 'any' and 'every' as well: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121775/what-is-the-difference-between-everywhere-and-anywhere?rq=1

Comment: Even if you could see ***any*** difference between the two words, that wouldn't necessarily imply you could see ***every*** difference.

Comment: If I have a plate of cookies, and I say *take any cookie*, I expect you to choose one. If I say *take every cookie*, I am offering you all the cookies on the plate.

Comment: The biggest difference is that _any_ (and all compounds containing _any_) is a [negative polarity item](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299), and can only occur grammatically in negative contexts. This is not true of _every_ and its compounds.  Consider _I looked everywhere_ vs *_I looked anywhere, Everyone enjoyed the party_ vs *_Anyone enjoyed the party._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Any*** chooses one item from a set (or a few)

> ***Every*** chooses all items from a set.

Consider everywhere vs anywhere, the set is places (from the 'where'). Everywhere means all places in the set. For example "I dropped the brush in the paint bucket and the paint got everywhere" means that the paint is now in all the places or in *every* place or everywhere. Whereas anywhere means just one place in the set, but we don't know which place for example "I have forgotten where I left the paint bucket, it could be anywhere by now." The paint bucket is only in one place, but we don't know which place, therefore it is in *any* possible place which means it is anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

"Every" is closer to "all".  "Any" does not imply "all", and perhaps only one.  "Every" has a more individual connotation (such as individual attention) than "all" (more like a blanket condition).